# Duplicate events in Shotwell

Tags: shotwell

I've imported an existing collection of photographs into Shotwell, and it organizes them into different events by date in the UI, and stores them by Year/Month in the filesystem.

This is great, just what I want. However, there is a problem. Although the filesystem layout is correct, and without duplicates, there are duplicate events for the same date in the UI:

[image: Screenshot of duplicate events]

This is probably a bug, and as such should be reported somewhere. However, **is there someway to easily merge all the duplicate events, either using the Shotwell UI or with a shell script?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shotwell creates new Events with each import, regardless if the photos you are importing could fit into an existing Event.  The thinking is that if you're importing photos from separate cameras (or another source), they may not be of the same "event" (i.e. one from a birthday party, another at the zoo or something).  This isn't perfect for everyone, and there is some thought to changing this behavior.

Unfortunately, there is no way to automatically merge the duplicate Events.  You can, however, manually merge Events by selecting all the photos in one Event and dragging them to a different Event in the sidebar.  If the photos are not taken on the same day, the Event will be renamed to represent that (i.e. "Thu, Feb 19 - 20, 2011").

Also note that you can Edit -> Undo this operation, which is useful if you make a mistake.  (You lose Undo when you close Shotwell, however.)

Answer (score 2):

A better way is to go to the month overview of events, and select 2 events (or more) - there is a 'merge' button at the bottom, so you can combine several events in one go &  the actual merge is faster as well, and the event list doesn't irritatingly scroll up either.